# Updating SharePoint List with Linked Access Database - New List Created Instead of Updating Old List

Tags: list, lookup-column, microsoft-access

When you've linked an Access Database to SharePoint lists, how do you make sure that saving the database updates the existing list instead of creating a new one, so that lookup columns pull from the up-to-date list?

Here's the specific problem I experienced: I used the "Move To SharePoint" command from Access to link the database to SharePoint. It created the appropriate lists on the SharePoint site, and in Access those now show up as linked tables (the icon is gold). However, when I added new entries to the table and saved the changes instead of updating the "Components" list, a new list "Components_1" was created.

In theory, I could delete the old "Components" list and rename the new "Components_1". However, I have a picture library with a lookup table that links items and components to their pictures. If I delete "Components," I will lose all that information.

What I need to be able to do is update "Components" on SharePoint so that I can select the new items from the lookup column in the Pictures Library.

Comment: There wasn't a really applicable reason for the bounty--I'm less concerned about official sources and more concerned with an answer that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Access and choose "Open". Choose "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation ()" in the list of document types. Choose your site and your list in the following menus. If you edit in your opened database and save it, the changes will be published automatically to your SharePoint list and no additional list is created on your site.

Edit: In the menu where you choose your site choose the option to link and not to import the data.